# How do I join two tables with summarize results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the query

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iltd_units),0) as 'nLTDUnt' , 
ISNULL(SUM(s.slh_iltd_amt),0) as 'nLTDAmt'  ,
ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iytd_units),0) as 'nYTDUnt',   
ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iytd_amt),0) as 'nYTDAmt' 
from title t LEFT join salehist s on t.ttl_cisbn13 = s.slh_cisbn  
where TTL_CSTATUS <> 'D' AND 
ttl_ctitleid+ttl_ceditionno= (select ttl_ctitleid+ttl_ceditionno from title where ttl_cisbn13 =  '9780203005309')
```

The results are:

```sql
nLTDUnt nLTDAmt nYTDUnt nYTDAmt
3379    108771.00   0   0.00
```

I have this second query

```sql
Select sls.sal_ipk,sls.sal_cisbn,sls.sal_cruletype,sls.sal_country,
      sls.sal_nqty,sls.sal_namtusd,sls.sal_nlistprusd
from sales sls left join ruletype r on sls.sal_cruletype = r.rut_crultype
 where sls.sal_acctmonth=6 and sls.sal_acctyear=2012 and
       sls.sal_ernipk IS NULL and sls.sal_lclientle=0 and 
       r.rut_lignore <> 1 AND sal_corigen<>'UK' and sls.sal_cisbn='9780203005309'
  order by sls.sal_cisbn
```

The results are:

```sql
sal_ipk sal_cisbn   sal_cruletype   sal_country sal_nqty    sal_namtusd sal_nlistprusd
1202    9780203005309   1   US  3   112.38  57.95
1203    9780203005309   1   US  -2  -81.14  59.95
```

I created a query to join the two querys

```sql
Select  sls.sal_ipk,sls.sal_cisbn,sls.sal_cruletype,
        sls.sal_country,sls.sal_nqty,sls.sal_namtusd,sls.sal_nlistprusd,
       sal1.nLTDAmt ,sal1.nLTDUnt ,sal1.nYTDAmt , sal1.nYTDUnt, sal1.ttl_cisbn13 
from sales sls left join ruletype r on sls.sal_cruletype = r.rut_crultype
        INNER JOIN (
           SELECT  t.ttl_cisbn13 ,  ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iltd_units),0) as 'nLTDUnt' ,   
 ISNULL(SUM (s.slh_iltd_amt),0) as 'nLTDAmt'  ,
 ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iytd_units),0) as 'nYTDUnt',    
 ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iytd_amt),0) as 'nYTDAmt' 
                 from title t left join salehist s on t.ttl_cisbn13 = s.slh_cisbn  
                     where TTL_CSTATUS <> 'D' AND 
                         ttl_ctitleid+ttl_ceditionno= (select ttl_ctitleid+ttl_ceditionno from title where ttl_cisbn13 = s.slh_cisbn     )
                         group by t.ttl_cisbn13 
                     ) AS sal1 on  ttl_cisbn13 = sls.sal_cisbn
  where sls.sal_acctmonth=6 and sls.sal_acctyear=2012 and
       sls.sal_ernipk IS NULL and sls.sal_lclientle=0 and 
       r.rut_lignore <> 1 AND sal_corigen<>'UK' and sls.sal_cisbn='9780203005309'
  order by sls.sal_cisbn 

 sal_ipk    sal_cisbn   sal_cruletype   sal_country sal_nqty    sal_namtusd sal_nlistprusd  nLTDAmt nLTDUnt nYTDAmt nYTDUnt
 1202   9780203005309   1   US  3   112.38  57.95   4310.00 110 0.00    0
1203    9780203005309   1   US  -2  -81.14  59.95   4310.00 110 0.00    0
```

But the result for the colums nLTDAmt,nLTDUnt,nYTDAmt,nYTDUnt is not the desired. It is only summarized only for 1 record.

I tried to do this query

```sql
Select sls.sal_ipk, sls.sal_cisbn, sls.sal_cruletype, sls.sal_country, sls.sal_nqty, sls.sal_namtusd, sls.sal_nlistprusd,
          (
           SELECT    ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iltd_units),0) as 'nLTDUnt' ,    ISNULL(SUM(s.slh_iltd_amt),0) as 'nLTDAmt'  ,
                       ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iytd_units),0) as 'nYTDUnt',      ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iytd_amt),0) as 'nYTDAmt' 
                 from title t left join salehist s on t.ttl_cisbn13 = s.slh_cisbn  
                     where TTL_CSTATUS <> 'D' AND 
                         ttl_ctitleid+ttl_ceditionno= (select ttl_ctitleid+ttl_ceditionno from title where ttl_cisbn13 = sls.sal_cisbn      )
                     ) AS sal1
        from sales sls left join ruletype r on sls.sal_cruletype = r.rut_crultype                   
  where sls.sal_acctmonth=6 and sls.sal_acctyear=2012 and
       sls.sal_ernipk IS NULL and sls.sal_lclientle=0 and 
       r.rut_lignore <> 1 AND sal_corigen<>'UK' and sls.sal_cisbn='9780203005309'
  order by sls.sal_cisbn
```

But I got the error Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

How do I do just a query with the results desired?

The results desired are

```
    sal_ipk sal_cisbn   sal_cruletype   sal_country sal_nqty    sal_namtusd sal_nlistprusd  nLTDAmt nLTDUnt nYTDAmt nYTDUnt ttl_cisbn13
    1202    9780203005309   1   US  3   112.38  57.95   108771.00   3379    0.00    0   9780203005309
    1203    9780203005309   1   US  -2  -81.14  59.95   108771.00   3379    0.00    0   9780203005309
```

I found the solution to the problem

`Select  sls.sal_ipk,sls.sal_cisbn,sls.sal_cruletype,
         sls.sal_country,sls.sal_nqty,sls.sal_namtusd,sls.sal_nlistprusd,
         sal1.nLTDAmt ,sal1.nLTDUnt ,sal1.nYTDAmt , sal1.nYTDUnt
 from sales sls left join ruletype r on sls.sal_cruletype = r.rut_crultype 
        left join title tt on tt.ttl_cisbn13=sls.sal_cisbn 
 INNER JOIN (
           SELECT  ttl_ctitleid,ttl_ceditionno,
                   ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iltd_units),0) as 'nLTDUnt' ,   
                   ISNULL(SUM(s.slh_iltd_amt),0) as 'nLTDAmt'  ,
                   ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iytd_units),0) as 'nYTDUnt',  
                   ISNULL(sum(s.slh_iytd_amt),0) as 'nYTDAmt' 
            from title t left join salehist s on t.ttl_cisbn13 = s.slh_cisbn  
                where t.TTL_CSTATUS <> 'D'
            group by  ttl_ctitleid,ttl_ceditionno   
                     ) AS sal1 
                  on  sal1.ttl_ctitleid= tt.ttl_ctitleid   
                      and sal1.ttl_ceditionno= tt.ttl_ceditionno 
  where sls.sal_acctmonth=6 and sls.sal_acctyear=2012 and
        sls.sal_ernipk IS NULL and sls.sal_lclientle=0 and 
        r.rut_lignore <> 1 AND sal_corigen<>'UK' 
  order by sls.sal_cisbn`

Comment: Can you maybe write what is expected result because I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Clean code helps order your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your last query doesn't work, you can't introduce multiple columns via subquery in the `SELECT` list like that, so I'd suggest sticking with fixing your `JOIN` query.

Since you need the `SUM()` across multiple records without grouping, you'll need to window the sum via `OVER()`:

```
SELECT  sls.sal_ipk
      , sls.sal_cisbn
      , sls.sal_cruletype
      , sls.sal_country
      , sls.sal_nqty
      , sls.sal_namtusd
      , sls.sal_nlistprusd
      , sal1.nLTDAmt
      , sal1.nLTDUnt
      , sal1.nYTDAmt
      , sal1.nYTDUnt
      , sal1.ttl_cisbn13
FROM    sales sls
INNER JOIN (SELECT    t.ttl_cisbn13
                    , ISNULL(SUM(s.slh_iltd_units) OVER(), 0) AS 'nLTDUnt'
                    , ISNULL(SUM(s.slh_iltd_amt) OVER(), 0) AS 'nLTDAmt'
                    , ISNULL(SUM(s.slh_iytd_units) OVER(), 0) AS 'nYTDUnt'
                    , ISNULL(SUM(s.slh_iytd_amt) OVER(), 0) AS 'nYTDAmt'
            FROM    title t
            LEFT JOIN salehist s 
               ON t.ttl_cisbn13 = s.slh_cisbn
            WHERE   TTL_CSTATUS <> 'D'
              AND ttl_ctitleid+ttl_ceditionno= (SELECT ttl_ctitleid+ttl_ceditionno 
                                                FROM title 
                                                WHERE ttl_cisbn13 =  sls.sal_cisbn)
            ) AS sal1 
  ON sal1.ttl_cisbn13 = sls.sal_cisbn
LEFT JOIN ruletype r 
   ON sls.sal_cruletype = r.rut_crultype
WHERE   sls.sal_acctmonth = 6
        AND sls.sal_acctyear = 2012
        AND sls.sal_ernipk IS NULL
        AND sls.sal_lclientle = 0
        AND r.rut_lignore <> 1
        AND sal_corigen <> 'UK'
        AND sls.sal_cisbn = '9780203005309'
ORDER BY sls.sal_cisbn
```

Comment: The problem is if I used groub by t.ttl_cisbn13, I don't have the summarize of all records. It is only summarized by 1 record.